# python module installed yet can't be imported since the actual folder is missing - what to do?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I got a weird situation and I don't know what to look into to resolve it.

I try to install `pyLDAvis==3.3.1` for `python-3.10` on a Windows machine. I succeed in doing so without any issues and see `pyLDAvis` in the output of `pip list`, however when I try to `import pyLDAvis` in python repl, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyLDAvis'`. In the `site-packages` folder I see `pyLDAvis-3.3.1.dist-info`, but no `pyLDAvis` folder - and the latter is nowhere to be found.

It is no surprise python can't import `pyLDAvis` then, but I don't understand how this happens and how can I resolve this situation. I'm not good with package distribution and whatnot, so I'd love some suggestions what to look for.

Also, the obligatory "it worked before" - with `python-3.6` I got both `pyLDAvis-3.2.2-py3.6.egg-info` and `pyLDAvis` and no issues with importing.

Answer (score 1):

One weird solution which I faced when I was importing cipher library. Please check the module folder name, is it the same or not I came across one time where there was a **capital C** problem. I know the solution seems weird but check for once. for me, it was cipher with **small c.**

Comment: Sadly this didn't help - I can't see any `PyLDAvis` or `pyldavis` or anything like that, and I can't import them either. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: have you tried venv (virtual environment)? try virtual environment then pip install library and check it with Pip show <module name>

Comment: Yeah, I tried venv to no avail. `pip show pyLDAvis` claims the package is in site-packages, though it is clearly not there. For now I resolved issue by installing v3.3.0, so it seems to be some weird packaging issue.